# MouseOver on ToggleButton to popup a Text

Tags: wpf

I am coding to popup a Text when `MouseOver` on `ToggleButton`. I got it too, but the real problem is that popped Text is not remains constant i.e., it continuously shaking on the `ToggleButton`. One more thing is that popped Text is appeared on the `ToggleButton` itself but it should be beneath of it. How can i get rid of this one?

Here is my Code looks

```
<ToggleButton x:Name="btn" Width="20" Height="15">
    <Image Source="../Images/flag_orange.ico"/>
</ToggleButton>
<Popup x:Name="popUp" IsOpen="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=btn, Mode=TwoWay}"
       StaysOpen="False" PlacementTarget="{Binding ElementName=btn}"
       Placement="Bottom" PopupAnimation="Slide" HorizontalOffset="-5"
       VerticalOffset="3">
    <Border Background="DarkGray">
        <TextBox Text="Its a place holder for user notes" x:Name="tbText"/>                         
    </Border>                    
</Popup>
<TextBlock x:Name="tbTextBlock" 
           Visibility="{Binding Path=IsMouseOver,ElementName=btn,Mode=OneWay,
                        Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisibilityConverter}}"
           Text="{Binding ElementName=tbText, Path=Text, Mode=TwoWay}" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `IsHitTestVisible="False"` on your TextBlock. The Mouseover is catched by the Textblock yet, so your mouse is not over the `ToggleButton` when the `TextBlock` appears.

To get the TextBlock beneath the ToggleButton use either a `Margin="0,15,0,0"` or a `StackPanel` to get those controls in order:

```
<StackPanel>
  <ToggleButton x:Name="btn" Width="20" Height="15">
    <Image Source="../Images/flag_orange.ico"/>
  </ToggleButton>
  <Popup x:Name="popUp" IsOpen="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=btn, Mode=TwoWay}"
         StaysOpen="False" PlacementTarget="{Binding ElementName=btn}"
         Placement="Bottom" PopupAnimation="Slide" HorizontalOffset="-5"
         VerticalOffset="3">
    <Border Background="DarkGray">
      <TextBox Text="Its a place holder for user notes" x:Name="tbText"/>
    </Border>
  </Popup>
  <TextBlock x:Name="tbTextBlock" 
         IsHitTestVisible="False"
         Visibility="{Binding Path=IsMouseOver,ElementName=btn,Mode=OneWay,
                      Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisibilityConverter}}"
         Text="{Binding ElementName=tbText, Path=Text, Mode=TwoWay}" />
</StackPanel>
```